# Fancybox options not having any effect

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I'm using fancybox 1.2.1 to open an iframe. My problem is my width, height and scrolling options don't actually do anything. Am I missing something? It just opens up at the default size.

Heres the call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a[rel=gallery]').fancybox({
    'width':920,
    'height':700,
    'scrolling':'no'
});
```

});

And heres the link in the page:

```
<a class="iframe" href="http://www.myiframedomain.com/page.jsp" rel="gallery">
  <img src="/img/content/button.png" width="210" height="115" alt="" />
</a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using the correct option names. `width` and `height` are defined in versions 1.3+.

For 1.2.1 use `frameWidth` and `frameHeight` instead. Look [here](http://fancybox.net/api/126) for all the options (and note that there is no `scrolling` in 1.2.1).

What you've posted works perfectly fine in 1.3.1 without change though, so I suggest you upgrade if you can.

Comment: Thanks, I came back to fancybox on a site and was using the newer documentation. I've upgraded and its fine now.